# SC_UNAUTHORIZED returns 403 in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-401

I have the following JWT filter

```
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException, MalformedJwtException {

        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        try {
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
                username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
            }
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        ...

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

But for some reason, I still get a 403 response instead of 401.

```
{
   "timestamp": "2020-07-08T15:59:50.696+0000",
   "status": 403,
   "error": "Forbidden",
   "message": "Access Denied",
   "path": "/ping"
}
```

Any idea what might be the issue? I tried different returns but they are all either 500 or 403.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai Doing that makes the response has no body, it just returns `401` but nothing else. Is there a way to keep the same body as in the question (status, error, message, etc.) but just changing the 403 to 401?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you are handling the response directly, you will have to do something like this

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{ ");
    sb.append("\"error\": \"Unauthorized\" ");
    sb.append("\"message\": \"Unauthorized\"");
    sb.append("\"path\": \"")
      .append(request.getRequestURL())
      .append("\"");
    sb.append("} ");

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
    response.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
    return;
```

Comment: Unfortunately using `sendError` instead of `setStatus` keeps the response at 403.

Comment: Yep, I just copy pasted your block.